# Tags should be markable as obsolete, and opted out of being suggested for new questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, asking-questions, suggested-tags

I don't know what algorithm is being used to come up with tag suggestions, but it probably wouldn't be too hard to add a simple filter that blocks it from suggesting "obsolete" tags.

[image: suggested tags including a tag that is clearly marked as obsolete]

I understand that "obsolete" isn't an official/ built-in mechanism, but it should be, and this designation should prevent such tags from being suggested for new questions.

Comment: Actually it is pretty hard to do that right. The right way is adding another field to the Tags table in the database, marking if the tag is obsolete or not, then developing the UI for that, who can mark etc. Doing it the wrong way, e.g. looking for the word "obsolete" in the tag wiki, is, well, wrong and prone to errors.

Comment: @Shadow Are you telling me that there are tag wiki excerpts that start with `OBSOLETE: ` that aren't on obsolete tags? *If* these exist, aren't *they* already problematic?

Comment: There's no rule or policy to have this in the tag wiki. Some also start with "**DON'T USE**", some mention it only later in the description, etc.

Comment: I don't really care how hard it is to implement.  
If suggested tags are a thing, and obsolete tags are a thing, then suggested tags shouldn't overlap with obsolete tags.

Comment: It's not that simple. Obsolete tags are not *official* thing, while suggested tags are. Or something like that. :/

Comment: I made an edit to make what you appear to be asking more explicit and clear; feel free to roll back or edit it further if you feel like the wording isn't quite right.

Comment: I would extend this idea to completely blocking obsolete tags from being added to new questions, not only from being suggested.

Answer (score 9):

Ah this is one of those 'clever' workarounds that people do when the system doesn't have some needed functionality.

People are careless in tag use. Sometimes we need to clear out/burninate an existing and often used tag, or discourage use of a tag for a feature that's obsolete.

Blocking the use of a tag needs staff assistance, and usually extraordinary cause. By labelling the tag as DO NOT USE or OBSOLETE, an observant user would avoid using that tag. This keeps things at least manageable, either giving us time to deal with the tag without flooding the front page, or keeping usage to folks who are carelessly tagging

The system is unaware of such uses and as such does not care, using other heuristics, like commonly used together tags to suggest it.

Comment: I understand this. My feature request is that the tag suggestions system be made aware.